# Load image from url in ListView Xamarin Forms Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I know there are several questions about this.

I have the following code:

```
Image image = new Image();
UriImageSource imgSource = new UriImageSource();

imgSource.SetBinding( UriImageSource.UriProperty, "ThumbnailUri" );
imgSource.Parent = image;

 ...
```

The problem is I don't know how to integrate `imgSource` to `image` object ?

Means how to add as child the `imgSource` to `image` ?

I set `imgSource.Parent = image;` but image is not visible in list view UI.

I have a model which contains a property like:

```
 Uri ThumbnailUri {get;set;}
```

And I want to display that image in list view.

Comment: use the Image's Source property

Comment: Awesome thanks, put it as answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image has a Source property

```
image.Source = imgSource;
```